# why the struct_iterable library does not give the field_value of a struct?

Tags: rust

I’am trying to use the struct_iterable library in the crate.io

here is my program :

```
#[derive(Iterable)]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Database {
    name: String,
    street: String,
    zip: String, 
}

let database = Database {
       name: "John".to_string(),
        street: "x avenue".to_string(),
        zip: "68901".to_string(),
};

for (field_name, field_value) in database.iter() {
   println!("field_name is {} ", field_name);
   println!("field_value  is {:?} ", field_value);           
} 

the result are : 

field_name is name 
field_value  is Any { .. } 
field_name is street 
field_value  is Any { .. } 
field_name is zip 
field_value  is Any { .. }
```

I was expecting to read the data loaded in the struct database.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Since `Any` doesn't constrain that the referent must implement `Debug`, its implementation of `Debug` provides the above output. It's the best it can do. `Any` is fairly limited since Rust doesn't have reflection. What are you trying to accomplish, exactly? There's probably a better way.

Comment: Jmb gave me the answer

Comment: Yes, that's the answer when all of the fields are `String`. If you have heterogeneous data types in your struct, you'll want to do something else. That's why I'm asking what your end goal is.

Answer (score 1):

The value may have any type, and not necessarily the same type for each field, but `field_value` must have a single type, so its type is `&dyn Any`. In your case, since you know that the values are all `String`s, you can get a value of the correct type with [`downcast_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast_ref):

```
for (field_name, field_value) in database.iter() {
   println!("field_name is {} ", field_name);
   println!("field_value  is {:?} ", field_value.downcast_ref::<String>().unwrap());           
}
```

Comment: thank's a lot, it's working